# Matplotlib Picking Legend with 'o' marker

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create legend that can toggle the visibility of each drawn object. Here is my code. It works on the line legend, but clicking on the dot legend object doesn't toggle the drawn object. In contrast, clicking outside the dot legend object will toggle the drawn object. This is counter-intuitive from the use perspective. Does anyone has any workaround to this issue?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
y = np.random.random(size=50)
x = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(y)), 10, replace=False)
line, = ax.plot(y, '-', label='line')
dot, = ax.plot(x, y[x], 'o', label='dot')
legend = ax.legend()

line_leg, dot_leg = legend.get_lines()
line_leg.set_picker(True)
line_leg.set_pickradius(5)
dot_leg.set_picker(True)
dot_leg.set_pickradius(5)

pickables = {}
pickables[line_leg] = line
pickables[dot_leg] = dot

def on_pick(event):
    leg = event.artist
    visible = leg.get_visible()
    visible = not visible
    pickables[leg].set_visible(visible)
    leg.set_visible(visible)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    
plt.connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when I increase the radius of the marker

```
dot_leg.set_pickradius(15)
```